# Change className of Link based on current URL, React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have Sidebar component with `Links`, and i need to change `Link` color when specific URL is opened.

What is best solution of this in React?

Comment: you have to show us some code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink) component and provide your class as value of `activeClassName` prop :

```
 <NavLink to="/faq" activeClassName="selected">
   FAQs
  </NavLink>
```

CSS rule could be like :

```
  .selected{
    color: blue
   }
```